# Python Selenium Web Driver - fail the test case deliberately if, "if condition is false"

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to automation.  Please help.

I want to fail the test case if the below condition is false.  How can I achieve that with python code in selenium webdriver. In below case, it passes the test even if the condition is false (BIAdisplayed is 359631 i expect it to fail).  See the execution result at the bottom.

```
    BIA = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/accordion/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[1]/input")
    BIAdisplayed = BIA.get_attribute("value")

    if BIAdisplayed == 0:
        try:
            print BIAdisplayed
        except Exception as e:
            print e
            raise # Raise the exception that brought you here 
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
```

=========================================================================

C:\Python26\Scripts>AMWebRegressionTest.py

Enter Alert AccessCode: TEST01

Enter Username: test

Enter Password:

....

359631

### .

Ran 6 tests in 394.925s

OK

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing *string* with *int*

```
BIA = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div/accordion/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/fieldset/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li[3]/ul/li[1]/input")

BIAdisplayed = BIA.get_attribute("value")

if BIAdisplayed == "0":
    try:
        print BIAdisplayed
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        raise # Raise the exception that brought you here 
driver.close()
driver.switch_to_window(main_window)
```

Comment: After making suggested change, i see some changes but still don't see what I expected.  BIAdisplayed is actually 359633.  so it throw the exception.  

C:\Python26\Scripts>AMWebRegressionTest.py


Enter Alert AccessCode: TEST02


Enter Username: test


Enter Password:

...

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Ran 6 tests in 352.546s

OK

Comment: See what? Same exception?

Comment: can someone help please?

Answer (score 0):

The main point is that your statement

```
    if BIAdisplayed == "0":
```

prevents Python to throw the exception.
BIAdisplayed == 359633 (?) so it does not satisfy this condition, so Python skips every code inside the if-block, including the part where the exception is thrown.

I am not sure what you want to do, but you could alter the if-block in

```
    if BIAdisplayed == "359633":
        raise Exception('BIAdisplayed == "359633"')
```